# Modify an array that is the value of a map

Tags: arrays, dictionary, go

If I have a map whose value is an array, how can I modify one element of the array?

Something like this:

```
m := make(map[string][4]int)
m["a"]=[...]int{0,1,2,3}
m["a"][2]=10
```

It won't compile: `prog.go:8: cannot assign to m["a"][2]`

I could copy the variable to an array, modify it and then copying it back to the map, but it seems to be very slow, specially for large arrays.

```
// what I like to avoid.
m := make(map[string][4]int)
m["a"] = [...]int{0, 1, 2, 3}
b := m["a"]
b[2] = 10
m["a"] = b
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 4):

Use a pointer. For example,

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    m := make(map[string]*[4]int)
    m["a"] = &[...]int{0, 1, 2, 3}
    fmt.Println(*m["a"])
    m["a"][2] = 10
    fmt.Println(*m["a"])
}
```

Output:

```
[0 1 2 3]
[0 1 10 3]
```

Comment: Thanks! The only issue I see with this is that for small arrays, there is a memory penalty by using pointers and could be a problem.

Comment: And, of course, that you have to allocate a new array every time, because now it is not automatically copied to the value of the map, only pointed to.

Comment: @siritinga, think about how the map is internally implemented.  Supposedly it has different mechanics to work with different value types.  How do you think it allocates your small arrays? I'd not be surprised if internally it does allocate them on the heap, just like you would do that should you use pointers. IOW, the exact behaviour is implementation defined and you're hence optimizing prematurely based entirely on your feelings.

Comment: True, I don't know how maps are internally mapped. But I tested a map with [4]byte and []byte of size 4, and [4]byte used much less memory, and in fact, it was a bit faster, at least to store it.

Answer (score 0):

Your map value ([arrays](http://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#arrays)) is not [addressable](http://tip.golang.org/ref/spec#Address_operators), From the [spec](http://tip.golang.org/ref/spec#Assignments):

> Each left-hand side operand must be addressable

Go for what [@peterSO](https://stackoverflow.com/users/221700/peterso) suggest if you really want to use `Arrays`, but I think that `Slices` here are more mush idiomatic.

Answer (score 0):

If you map strings to slices, rather than to arrays, this works:

```
m := make(map[string][]int)
m["a"] = []int{0, 1, 2, 3}
fmt.Println(m["a"])
m["a"][2] = 10
fmt.Println(m["a"])
```

Comment: Oh, interesting. Slices are more like pointers (to an internal array) so I suppose that is the reason.

Comment: Right, slices are references to arrays. If I understand Go's usage of slices and arrays (and it's quite possible that I do not) this is the intended idiomatic way to perform this kind of operation.